# How to fix error VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `SectionList` inside a `ScrollView` and i'm getting the error `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

I've tried to use `Flatlist` instead of `SectionList` but i'm having the same issue.

How can i fix this error ? Should i use `.map` instead to render my components ? because `.map` isn't ideal when there is a lot of data

The structure of the component is :

```js
<SafeAreaView>
  <FocusedStatusBar/>
  <ScrollView>
  <DetailsHeader/> 
  <SubInfo / >
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text> Text </Text>
    </View>
    
    <Text> Text </Text>
    <FormTextInput/>
    <FormTextInput/> 
    <FormTextInput/>
    
    <Text> Text </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text> Text </Text> 
      <Image/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {showModal && ( 
      <View>
        <View>
        <Image/> 
        <TextInput/>
        </View>
        
        <SectionList 
          sections = {[
            { title: 'D',
             data: ['Devin', 'Dan', 'Dominic']
            },{
             title: 'J',
             data: ['Jackson','James', 'Jillian', 'Jimmy', 'Joel','John', 'Julie'],
             }]}
             
          renderItem = {({item}) => <Text> {item} </Text>}
          renderSectionHeader = {({section}) => (<Text>{section.title} </Text>)}
          keyExtractor = {item => `basicListEntry-${item}`}
         /> 
      </View>
      )}
      
    <Text> TEXT </Text> 
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text> {file.filename} </Text> 
      <Image/> 
     </TouchableOpacity>

     <View>
      <TextButton/> 
     </View> 
    </View> 
  </ScrollView> 
</SafeAreaView>
```